# all sites search return less than expected

Tags: search

Guys its been reported to me that people are not getting back the results they expect when doing a search using the all sites scope.  Looking at the scopes in central admin i've noticed that the items count is only 1020.  Is this the number of items available to search on.  1020 seems extremely low for the entire intranet. What does the count refer to?

Answer (score 1):

There are many posibilities why you would not see them all, but here is what you could start checking:

- SP-CA check in the Web Application User Policy and make sure your Search Crawl account has Full Read permissions
- Check Crawl Log in the Search Service application associated with the
  Web Application for errors/warnings.
- Check Content Sources make sure they are proper
- Check Shared Search Scopes on the rules
- Make sure Libraries/Lists from which results we're suppossed to be retrieved if "Enable search..." checkbox is enabled.

Run a Full Crawl and watch Crawl log and ULS logs

Comment: what do i need to check in the content sources.  Currently the rules are set to all content and to exlude contentclass = urn:content-class:SPSPeople

Comment: do you have listed all the Web Application URLS?

Comment: yes they are all in there.  Ive checked everything you said above and all looks ok to me

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its any help to you but you could try this and see if your search scope is setup properly?

SharePoint Portal Server 2003
Creating Search Scopes for Sites in the Site Directory
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/creating-search-scopes-for-sites-in-the-site-directory-HA001164852.aspx

SharePoint Server 2007
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/define-scopes-for-searches-HA010241119.aspx

Search scopes for end users in SharePoint 2010
sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=575

I hope this helps you!

Good luck :)